# A symmetric inequality with three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Here is an inequality I came across in a book that I was doing:-

Prove that for all $a,b,c\gt 0$ $$\frac {a+b+c}{(abc)^{1/3}}+\frac {8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\ge 4$$ I have no idea about how to approach the problem.

Comment: The problem if I post them as 3 separate problems is that I will have to wait for 20 minutes after each question to post the next question and it reduces the span of asking questions in 1 day ..also you are welcome to give an answer to an individual question separately..

Comment: What else can I do? Do you have an alternative?...because I have a lot of questions to ask...

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi,you can ask one problem on post.or you will devoload it

Comment: @math110, what do you mean by devoload? and well what is the problem with posting 3 questions in one go??

Comment: The problem with posting three different questions in one go is that it doesn't fit the model - if someone answers part 1, and someone else answers part 2 which answer deserves to be accepted? Another problem at the moment is that suggesting you have a lot of similar questions to ask makes other users think that they are being asked to do your work for you. You should think about picking a few key questions which will help you to learn the technique for the others.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, you could usefully tell us what you already know about inequalities. What section of the book do they appear in, and what topics does that section cover. At the moment only the first question shows any context or effort, and people will be reluctant to share their thoughts if you have not shared yours.

Comment: The others already explained this. One question per question. Wrappers for several questions don't work and are frowned upon. If this takes you to the daily question limit, that is a sign that you need to prioritize your questions. Or, to put it more bluntly, that is YOUR PROBLEM.

Comment: Then the friendly piece of advice from your friendly community moderator who coincidentally also has two bronze medals from past IMOs. The way to improve your ability to solve tough contest problems is to think about tough contest problems. Hard. VERY HARD. HARDER STILL. If you feel like asking a question before you have thought about it for a week or so, you are not thinking about it hard enough. Did I forget to add that you should try HARDER. Posting contest questions with 20 minute intervals makes those who have been there shake their heads in disbelief.

Comment: I am editing the question and leaving only Q2, so that the users have a definite question to work on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shorter way of dealing with it is $\displaystyle \left(\frac{a+b+b+c+c+a}{3}\right)^3 \ge (a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$

Thus, $\displaystyle \frac {a+b+c}{(abc)^{1/3}}+\frac {8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} \ge \frac {a+b+c}{(abc)^{1/3}}+\frac {27abc}{(a+b+c)^3}$

Set, $\displaystyle t = \frac {a+b+c}{(abc)^{1/3}}$ then the above inequality becomes, $\displaystyle t + \frac{27}{t^3} \ge 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{t^3}{27}.\frac{27}{t^3}} = 4$

(which is just Am-Gm inequality with $\displaystyle \frac{t}{3},\frac{t}{3},\frac{t}{3},\frac{27}{t^3}$)

Comment: Nice +1,  what I had in mind was similar, will post separately.

Answer (score 8):

It pays to recognise AM-GMs fast. Rewrite as

$$\frac{a+b}{2(abc)^{1/3}}+\frac{b+c}{2(abc)^{1/3}}+\frac{c+a}{2(abc)^{1/3}}+\frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} \ge 4$$

and perhaps you will see it instantly...

Comment: What can you say :-)

Comment: @Macavity please can u elaborate?

Comment: @novak Use $a+b+c=(a+b)/2+(b+c)/2+(c+a)/2$ to rewrite the LHS as shown. Then do AM-GM for all four terms, and see the cancellations. Try it out and it should be evident.

Answer (score 0):

for Q2 we can write
$\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{xyz}+\frac{8(xyz)^3}{(x^2+y^3)(y^3+z^3)(z^3+x^3)}\geq 4$
now let $y=x+u,z=x+u+v,u,v\geq 0$ and after some algebra we obtain
$$\left( 6\,{u}^{2}+6\,uv+6\,{v}^{2} \right) {x}^{10}+ \left( 34\,{u}^{
3}+51\,{u}^{2}v+69\,u{v}^{2}+26\,{v}^{3} \right) {x}^{9}+ \left( 120\,
{u}^{4}+240\,{u}^{3}v+405\,{u}^{2}{v}^{2}+285\,u{v}^{3}+84\,{v}^{4}
 \right) {x}^{8}+ \left( 324\,{u}^{5}+810\,{u}^{4}v+1452\,{u}^{3}{v}^{
2}+1368\,{u}^{2}{v}^{3}+666\,u{v}^{4}+132\,{v}^{5} \right) {x}^{7}+
 \left( 624\,{u}^{6}+1872\,{u}^{5}v+3444\,{u}^{4}{v}^{2}+3768\,{u}^{3}
{v}^{3}+2394\,{u}^{2}{v}^{4}+822\,u{v}^{5}+120\,{v}^{6} \right) {x}^{6
}+ \left( 824\,{u}^{7}+2884\,{u}^{6}v+5544\,{u}^{5}{v}^{2}+6650\,{u}^{
4}{v}^{3}+4996\,{u}^{3}{v}^{4}+2286\,{u}^{2}{v}^{5}+584\,u{v}^{6}+64\,
{v}^{7} \right) {x}^{5}+ \left( 742\,{u}^{8}+2968\,{u}^{7}v+6090\,{u}^
{6}{v}^{2}+7882\,{u}^{5}{v}^{3}+6670\,{u}^{4}{v}^{4}+3666\,{u}^{3}{v}^
{5}+1246\,{u}^{2}{v}^{6}+232\,u{v}^{7}+18\,{v}^{8} \right) {x}^{4}+
 \left( 450\,{u}^{9}+2025\,{u}^{8}v+4500\,{u}^{7}{v}^{2}+6300\,{u}^{6}
{v}^{3}+5898\,{u}^{5}{v}^{4}+3720\,{u}^{4}{v}^{5}+1528\,{u}^{3}{v}^{6}
+372\,{u}^{2}{v}^{7}+45\,u{v}^{8}+2\,{v}^{9} \right) {x}^{3}+ \left( 
176\,{u}^{10}+880\,{u}^{9}v+2133\,{u}^{8}{v}^{2}+3252\,{u}^{7}{v}^{3}+
3360\,{u}^{6}{v}^{4}+2394\,{u}^{5}{v}^{5}+1150\,{u}^{4}{v}^{6}+344\,{u
}^{3}{v}^{7}+54\,{u}^{2}{v}^{8}+3\,u{v}^{9} \right) {x}^{2}+ \left( 40
\,{u}^{11}+220\,{u}^{10}v+582\,{u}^{9}{v}^{2}+969\,{u}^{8}{v}^{3}+1104
\,{u}^{7}{v}^{4}+882\,{u}^{6}{v}^{5}+488\,{u}^{5}{v}^{6}+176\,{u}^{4}{
v}^{7}+36\,{u}^{3}{v}^{8}+3\,{u}^{2}{v}^{9} \right) x+4\,{u}^{12}+24\,
{u}^{11}v+69\,{u}^{10}{v}^{2}+125\,{u}^{9}{v}^{3}+156\,{u}^{8}{v}^{4}+
138\,{u}^{7}{v}^{5}+86\,{u}^{6}{v}^{6}+36\,{u}^{5}{v}^{7}+9\,{u}^{4}{v
}^{8}+{u}^{3}{v}^{9}
\geq 0$$
which is true.
Sonnhard.

Comment: My God...Dr.Sonhard...did you really do the algebra??...Although the method is hardly feasible....I really appreciate the effort...would you try and find a better proof...

Comment: yes i will try it and i will try to solve the other inequality

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I did try quite hard...I came across these problems on monday...but you can already see what the answer to question number 2 is like...

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, thanks in advance..

Comment: how would you prove the inequality?

Comment: where are the other inequalities?

Comment: I don't have a proof...so I am asking the question here..the first question is there...I am posting the 3rd question...

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, would you please give a solution to the question I have currently posted as a bounty question...the one in which you commented that i would get an answer using vieta jumping